# How to serialize a string to a dict with pydantic

Tags: python, boto3, pydantic

I am using Boto3 to retrieve configuration information from our AWS instance.   I am trying to use pydantic to keep my data clean as I parse it.   I haven't used dataclasses or pydantic in the past.   AWS returns JSON with the information.  There is a nested dictionary that they return as a string...

```
{
'accountId': '12354,  
'arn': 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:1234-NotificationForwarder',  
'availabilityZone': 'Not Applicable',  
'awsRegion': 'ap-southeast-2',  
'configuration': '{"functionName":"aws-controltower-NotificationForwarder","functionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:1234:function:aws-controltower-NotificationForwarder","runtime":"python3.6","role":"arn:aws:iam::1234:role/aws-controltower-ForwardSnsNotificationRole","handler":"index.lambda_handler","codeSize":473,"description":"SNS '  
'message forwarding function for aggregating account '  
'notifications.","timeout":60,"memorySize":128,"lastModified":"2020-06-23T16:11:27.781+0000","codeSha256":"blah\\u003d","version":"$LATEST","tracingConfig":{"mode":"PassThrough"},"revisionId":"blah","layers":[],"state":"Active","lastUpdateStatus":"Successful","fileSystemConfigs":[],"packageType":"Zip","architectures":["x86_64"],"ephemeralStorage":{"size":512},"snapStart":{"applyOn":"None","optimizationStatus":"Off"}}',  
'configurationItemCaptureTime': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 18, 3, 10, 30, 444000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),  
'configurationItemMD5Hash': '',  
'configurationItemStatus': 'OK',  
'configurationStateId': '1234',  
'relatedEvents': [],  
'relationships': [{'relationshipName': 'Is associated with ',  
'resourceName': 'aws-controltower-ForwardSnsNotificationRole',  
'resourceType': 'AWS::IAM::Role'}],  
'resourceId': 'aws-controltower-NotificationForwarder',  
'resourceName': 'aws-controltower-NotificationForwarder',  
'resourceType': 'AWS::Lambda::Function',  
'version': '1.3'
}
```

the configuration field is a dictionary but it is enclosed in ticks which makes it a string.   What is the best way to convert that to a dict as part of my datamodel?

I assume I would use a class to do that but I'm unclear as to how to do that.   I tried to do a json

I have the below class..

```
class LambdaConfig(BaseModel):
    functionName: str
    functionArn: str
    runtime: str
    role: str
    handler: str
    codeSize: int
    description: str
    memorySize: str
class Lambda(BaseModel):
    arn: str
    availabilityZone: str
    awsRegion: str
    configuration: LambdaConfig
    configurationItemCaptureTime: datetime.datetime

    relationships: List
    resourceId: str
    resourceName: str
    resourceType: str
    supplementaryConfiguration: Dict
    version: str
    tags: dict
```

I can't figure out how I can convert the str into dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [validator decorator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/) to make the parsing:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
import json

class LambdaConfig(BaseModel):
    functionName: str
    functionArn: str
    runtime: str
    role: str
    handler: str
    codeSize: int
    description: str
    timeout: int
    memorySize: int
    lastModified: str
    codeSha256: str
    version: str
    tracingConfig: dict
    revisionId: str
    layers: list
    state: str
    lastUpdateStatus: str
    fileSystemConfigs: list
    packageType: str
    architectures: list
    ephemeralStorage: dict
    snapStart: dict

class Lambda(BaseModel):
    arn: str
    availabilityZone: str
    awsRegion: str
    configuration: LambdaConfig
    configurationItemCaptureTime: datetime.datetime
    relationships: List[dict]
    resourceId: str
    resourceName: str
    resourceType: str
    supplementaryConfiguration: Dict
    version: str
    tags: dict
    
    @validator('configuration', pre=True)
    def parse_configuration(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return json.loads(value)
        return value
```

It detects if the 'configuration' field is a string and parses it to a dict.

```
lambda_obj = Lambda(**data)
print(lambda_obj.configuration)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it would be a validator but I thought I would need to do something special rather just a json.loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you structure contains fields with datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 20, 11, 48, 1, tzinfo=tzutc()) you can get JSONDecodeError, for avoid this you can use `eval`

Example raw structure as answer from server

```
{'config': "{'action': None,\n 'api_version': None,\n 'count': 1,\n 'first_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 20, 11, 48, 1, tzinfo=tzutc())}
```

```py
from typing import Optional
import datetime

from dateutil.tz import tzutc


class ConfigAWS(BaseModel):
    action: Optional[str]
    api_version: Optional[str]
    count: Optional[int]
    first_timestamp: Optional[datetime.datetime]


class AWS(BaseModel):
        config: ConfigAWS

    @validator('config', pre=True)
    def parse_event(cls, value):
        return eval(value)

# example usage

conf = ... # below example raw answer from server

AWS(**conf)
```